# Speedup broadcast finds with mongos

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a sharded cluster with each shard being a replica set. Sharding with a hashed index. Each find query results in millions of documents loaded from each shard.

I have a setup to directly connect to each node to get the best possible speed. But since this is not really officially supported I tried using mongos. Queries get way slower with mongos. I'm wondering how to speed things up.

1. mongos needs a lot of RAM for doing its job.
2. It looks like mongos is doing some caching or something before returning the result.

What I would expect is: mongos connects to each shard and just returns the results as they come from the individual nodes. Maybe round-robin. Don't need any sorting. Just a collecting from all shards.

Seems this job is too simple for mongos. ;-)

Some advice how to use mongos in this scenario, or is there no way to optimize its logic?

Comment: Hi Sebastian Bauer, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask for a clarification - have you tried using `explain` on your query, to see if it says anything useful about the mongos integration stage? The docs on [cluster query routing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#routing-and-results-process) suggest that it can help.
PS remember to [edit] your question as necessary, editing and re-editing is encouraged to make questions as good as possible.

Comment: @VinceBowdren, thank you for this hint. `explain` seems to be very helpful for aggregation operations, which is not used here. mongos seems the only official way to talk to an sharded cluster, but I get way better performance with direct connections. I guess I just will stay with this approach.